# Best way to handle links in footnotes from an accessibility point of view

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, uiaccessibility

When I have a screen reader read my page and come to a footnote in the body of my page, I include the footnote with a hidden text to reference it.  I have a scenario where there is a link within the footnote. What are the best practices to handle a link within the footnote when referencing it since users do not have access to links within screen-only content?  Making screen readers read out the link is a bit too much.  Example is:

Virtualization<sup>2</sup> and cloud computing ...(paragraph con't)

** at the bottom of content/page, as a footnote, I have

<sup>2 - To learn more about virtualization, [click here](http://#).</sup>

As anyone faced this scenario before?  I will be appreciated to hear how you handle it.

Comment: I don't understand well what do you mean by screen-only. Can you elaborate your example a little more ?

Comment: @QuentinC after rereading my post, I think it should be screen-reader only  content, so the sentence becomes:

What are the best practices to handle a link within the footnote when referencing it since users do not have access to links within screen-reader-only content?

I realized a footnote is unnecessary as the link can be in the body content with an aria-label attribute.   I have submitted a request to the folks above if they are okay with the change.  But if they disagree, what is the best approach since a link is not accessible within a screen reader?

Comment: Why are you hiding the footnote if you have a link to it? It could be just the way things are phrased and I am misunderstanding, if you want to put a quick HTML snippet up that demonstrates the problem, we can help more easily and it will get rid of the confusion!